# Tampermonkey script is not redirecting to the expected URL?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, href, tampermonkey

I am trying to replace the visited URL with another URL whenever certain search terms are used.

However browsing bing.com for the term `"foobar"` results in the URL `bing.com/www.google.com.au` instead of just `google.com.au`.

I have tried using both `location.href` and `location.replace()`:

```
var OldUrl = location.href
var NewUrl = "www.google.com.au";

var arr = ["foobar"];
for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; ++i) {
    if (OldUrl.indexOf(arr[i]) != -1) {
        // str contains arr[i]
        location.href = NewUrl; 
        //location.replace(NewUrl);
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You must prefix your url with a protocol (such as `http://` or `https://`) otherwise it is handled like a relative url.

Comment: @CollinD Thanks appending the protocol worked. If you write the answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1):

URLs are treated as relative unless prefixed with a protocol. To solve your issue in particular, I'd suggest

```
var NewUrl = 'https://www.google.com.au'
```